# How to convert Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> into JsonObject

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, metrics

I'm trying to convert Map> into JSON Object. I have tried two different ways to convert.

1. Using ObjectMapper:

Here is the code looks like but returning null.

```
       @GetMapping("/showRawKafkaMetrics")
            public String getMetrics() throws JsonProcessingException {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
                for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry
                        .getListenerContainers()) {
    // The below map of metrics I'm trying to convert into json Object
                    Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> metrics = messageListenerContainer.metrics();
                     metrics.forEach((clientid, metricMap) -> {
                        log.info("Client Id:"+sb.toString());
                         String json = null;
                         try {
                             json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(metricMap);
                         } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                         log.info("JSON Metrics :"+json);
                        metricMap.forEach((metricName, metricValue) -> {
                            log.info("------------ Metric name: " + metricName.name() + " ----------- Metric value: "
                                    + metricValue.metricValue() + LINE_BREAK);
                        });
                    });
                }
                String metrics = sb.toString();
                return metrics;
            }
```

```
****2. Using JSON Object 

Here is the code looks like:****
```

```
         @GetMapping("/showRawKafkaMetrics")
                    public String getMetrics() throws JsonProcessingException {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
                        for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry
                                .getListenerContainers()) {
    // The below map of metrics I'm trying to convert into json Object
    // The below map of metrics I'm trying to convert into json Object

                            Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> metrics = messageListenerContainer.metrics();

                            metrics.forEach((clientid, metricMap) -> {
                                log.info("Client Id:"+sb.toString());
                                metricMap.forEach((metricName, metricValue) -> {
                                    log.info("------------ Metric name: " + metricName.name() + " ----------- Metric value: "
                                            + metricValue.metricValue() + LINE_BREAK);
                                    jsonObject.add(metricName.toString(), (JsonElement) metricValue);
                                    log.info("JSON METRICS:"+jsonObject);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                        String metrics = sb.toString();
                        return metrics;
                    }
```

In both of the cases I'm getting null pointers. Can anyone suggest me best way to convert the Map of Metrics into JsonObject. So further I can process that to create a dashboard.

Comment: You tried Jackson and native JSON, but have you tried GSON though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Spring do it for you. Add `@ResponseBody` and `produces = "application/json"`.

Question is about `Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>>`, which is what is returned by `messageListenerContainer.metrics()`, but you have a list of those `messageListenerContainer` objects, so what you really want is a `List` of them, to be converted to JSON.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/showRawKafkaMetrics", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String getMetrics() {
    List<Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MessageListenerContainer container : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers())
        list.add(container.metrics());
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the 500 responseCode with the above changes. Throwing some exception. "message": "Type definition error: [simple type, classorg.apache.kafka.common.metrics.KafkaMetric]; nested exception iscom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.KafkaMetric and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

Comment: @TechGeek So that would also be why you get null values, because it failed and you swallowed the exception, leaving variable `json` with its pre-initialized null value. Which means you need to either create a Serializer for the `Metric`, or you need to convert it into a POJO object that can be serialized. See e.g. [Jackson How-To: Custom Serializers](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work and you're getting `null` is you're trying to serialize `MetricName` and `Metric` classes themselves.

I suppose, the example with `ObjectMapper` throws an JsonProcessingException which is just printed in console, that's why `json` is kept `null`.

To make this work with fasterxml `ObjectMapper` prepare your own DTO classes structure or just use [java.util.Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and serialize it with `ObjectMapper#writeValueAsString` for example.

See [FasterXML docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs) and examples.